# Ricci theorem and 4-th divergence of Energy-momentum/ Einstein tensor

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I know that Ricci theorem says that absolute differential of metric $g_{ij}$ :

$D(g_{ij}) = (\nabla_{k} g_{ij}) \text{d}x^{k} = 0$

So we can write : $\nabla_{k} g_{ij} = 0$

with $k$ that can be equal to $i$ or $j$.

On the other side, in General relativity, we have the 4-th divergence of $G_{\mu\nu}$ and $T_{\mu\nu}$ which is equal to 0 :

$\nabla_{\mu}T_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_{\mu}G_{\mu\nu} = 0$

Can we do the link between Ricci theorem for metric $g_{ij}$ and these 4-th divergences equal to zero ?

I mean, we cannot have (unlike with Ricci theorem) :

$\nabla_{k}T_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_{k}G_{\mu\nu} = 0$ for $k\neq \mu$ and $k\neq \nu$, isn't it ?

So, can we say, from a particular point of view, that Ricci theorem is more general, in the way that we have for any $k$ index (including $i$ or $j$) : $\nabla_{k} g_{ij} = 0$ ??

**UPDATE 1:**

You say that "The tensor equation $\nabla_{\rho} g_{\mu\nu} = 0$ ensures invariance of quantities such as $g_{\mu\nu}v^{\mu} w^{\nu}$ under parallel transportations : how to prove it ?

Maybe If I take (with $\tau$ curvilinear abscissa) : $\nabla_{\rho} g_{\mu\nu} \dfrac{\text{d}x^{\rho}}{\text{d}\tau} = 0\quad\quad(1)$,

which would imply :

$(\partial_{\rho} g_{\mu\nu} - g_{\mu\alpha}\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\rho\nu} - g_{\nu\alpha}\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\rho\mu}) \dfrac{\text{d}x^{\rho}}{\text{d}\tau} = 0$

but how to introduce $v^{\mu}$ and $w^{\nu}$ ?

I know that elementary length (like $\text{d}\tau$ above) $\text{d}s^2 = g_{\mu\nu} \text{d}x^{\mu} \text{d}x^{\nu}$ is invariant, so we could have :

$1 = g_{\mu\nu} \dfrac{\text{d}x^{\mu}}{\text{d}s} \dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}s} = g_{\mu\nu} v^{\mu} w^{\nu} = \text{constant}\quad\quad(2)$

but how to connect (2) and (1) ? or get (2) from (1) ?

Any help is welcome, regards

Comment: Maybe it helps if you recall, first of all, that a connection and its covariant derivative is a geometric notion that is independent of a metric. That is, you can introduce a connection in a manifold without metric, or in a manifold with metric but keeping the two independent (cf. "teleparallel" formulations of general relativity).

The condition $\nabla g =0$ selects one particular connection among all possible ones; it is not a Ricci identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ``divergence-free'' equations,

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu} = \nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}=0
\end{equation}
are just conservation laws (remember that the repeated index $\mu$ is summed so the above equations are continuity equations that suggest local conservation).

The fact that $\nabla_{\rho}g_{\mu\nu}=0$ is a completely different statement. To make it more obvious, remember that the metric tensor is essentially nothing more than the inner product of your axes unit vectors; it is a way of saying how ``much perpendicular your coordinates are''. The tensor equation $\nabla_{\rho}g_{\mu\nu}=0$ ensures invariance of quantities such as $g_{\mu\nu}w^{\mu}v^{\nu}$ under parallel transportations and it basically comes from the strong equivalence principle and the fact that the metric tensor is a ... tensor! (in flat spacetime $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, i.e. local inertial frames, the equation $\partial_{\rho}\eta_{\mu\nu}$ holds so it must hold for all frames of reference).

To sum it up, $\nabla_{\rho}g_{\mu\nu}=0$ is a unique tensor equation holding for the metric tensor itself, but $\nabla_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu} = \nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}=0$ are just manifestations of conservation laws in curved spacetimes.

**UPDATE 1**

The invariance of a quantity $(\dots)$ under parallel transportation along a direction with tangent 4-vector $t^{\rho}$ is expressed by the condition $t^{\rho}\nabla_{\rho}(\dots)=0$. For the invariant quantity $g_{\mu\nu}w^{\mu}v^{\nu}$ this means,
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
t^{\rho}\nabla_{\rho} (g_{\mu\nu}w^{\mu}v^{\nu}) &= t^{\rho}\nabla_{\rho}g_{\mu\nu}w^{\mu}v^{\nu} + t^{\rho}g_{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\rho}w^{\mu}v^{\nu} + t^{\rho}g_{\mu\nu}w^{\mu}\nabla_{\rho}v^{\nu} \\
&= t^{\rho}\nabla_{\rho}g_{\mu\nu}w^{\mu}v^{\nu} = 0 \\
^{\text{To hold for any }t^{\rho}, w^{\mu}, v^{\nu}}\Rightarrow \nabla_{\rho}g_{\mu\nu} = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

where the fact that parallel transportation of 4-vectors also means $t^{\rho}\nabla_{\rho}w^{\mu} = t^{\rho}\nabla_{\rho}v^{\nu} = 0$ was used.

Comment: -@Panos C. thanks for your remark, could you take a look at my **UPDATE 1** for a last precision ?

Comment: @Panos: some authors disagree on calling those divergences "conservation laws". See e.g. Pauli, *Theory of Relativity* (Pergamon 1958), § 21; Eddington: *The Mathematical Theory of Relativity* (2nd ed., Cambridge U. Press 1930), § 59; Landau & Lifshitz: *The Classical Theory of Fields* (4th ed., Butterworth-Heinemann 1994), § 96.

Comment: I have updated my response to answer your last update in your question.